# Css to create this table view

Tags: css

[image]

I am creating this custom card component . I am a little confused , what is the easiest way to create the table view.

Comment: i edited my post, btw if i helped/solved you pls checkmark my post

Comment: Can you share a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for what you've tried in your card component?

Comment: @xAtifx I got it done my own way but I liked ur approach too. Thnx for the help

Comment: no problem im glad i helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.row {
  display: flex !important;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.mt-0 {
  margin-top: 0 !important;
}

.mb-0 {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}

.border-grey {
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5 !important;
}

.textCenter {
  text-align: center !important;
}
.p-10 {
  padding: 10px !important;
}

.widthMinContent {
  width: min-content !important;
}
```

```html
 <div className="row">
                <div class="border-grey widthMinContent textCenter p-10">
                  <p class="mb-0">Applicants</p>
                  <h4 class="mt-0">10</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="border-grey widthMinContent textCenter p-10">
                  <p class="mb-0">Views</p>
                  <h4 class="mt-0">50</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="border-grey widthMinContent textCenter p-10">
                  <p class="mb-0">Shares</p>
                  <h4 class="mt-0">0</h4>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Firstly, of course theres better/shorter answer than this but since im first to answer this is my answer:

```
 <div className="row">
                <div className="border-grey widthMinContent textCenter p-10">
                  <p className="mb-0">Applicants</p>
                  <h4 className="mt-0">10</h4>
                </div>
                <div className="border-grey widthMinContent textCenter p-10">
                  <p className="mb-0">Views</p>
                  <h4 className="mt-0">50</h4>
                </div>
                <div className="border-grey widthMinContent textCenter p-10">
                  <p className="mb-0">Shares</p>
                  <h4 className="mt-0">0</h4>
                </div>
              </div>
```

And css:

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.mt-0 {
  margin-top: 0 !important;
}

.mb-0 {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}

.border-grey {
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5 !important;
}

.textCenter {
  text-align: center !important;
}
.p-10 {
  padding: 10px !important;
}
.widthMinContent {
  width: min-content !important;
}
```

Comment: Seeing as how this question is tagged with `react` and `styled-components` OP is likely looking for a more React-centric solution over vanilla HTML and CSS.

Comment: oh sorry didnt knew it was styled-component... i dont really know styled component that much so he can adjust himself... sorry

Comment: No worries, just pointing it out. It's still not even clear if OP is *actually* using the `styled-components` library, or if they just tagged it because they are just trying to *style* a react component.

Comment: Please could you add a verbal explanation of what your code does.

Comment: @DrewReese yeah I was looking for a more react-centric solution but I was open for a vanilla html css answer too so I used both tags